# ASUS pb278 1440p monitor only has an option up to 1080p. GTX 780 graphics card

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, resolution, asus, nvidia-settings

Have been looking for a fix for this since two days ago and after a good number of hours searching I finally decided to make a post about this. So as the title says in the NVIDIA settings panel there is no option for any resolution above 1920x1080 for my 2560x1440 monitor. Under additional drivers I have tried both proprietary NVIDIA drivers(331.113 & 331.113-updates), as well as Nouveau display drivers. Under NVDIDA x server settings I've tried changing the ViewportIn to 2560x1440 instead of 1920x1080, It does make the things on screen smaller (to scale as if it actually was the right resolution) but does not increase the resolution. Also my monitor is plugged into my card using the HDMI connector. I appreciate any help and would be incredibly grateful to anyone whom could help me solve this issue. Thanks!

EDIT!! About halfway down the page!

Here is the output from xrandr:

Code:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     60.0     50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        75.0     59.9     59.9  
   480x576        50.0  
   480x480        59.9  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is the ouput for lspci | grep VGA

Code:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX 780] (rev a1)
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you'd like me to type into the console in order to resolve this issue, or to shed more light on what the problem is!

EDIT START

Okay!! Something really funny happened while I was following another users forum post. This is what I tried:

```
max@luxBox:~$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

max@luxBox:~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

max@luxBox:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*    50.0     59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576       50.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480       60.0     59.9  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  2560x1440 (0x303)  241.5MHz
    h: width  2560 start 2600 end 2632 total 2720 skew    0 clock   88.8KHz
    v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock   60.0Hz
  2560x1440_60.00 (0x304)  312.2MHz
    h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock   89.5KHz
    v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock   60.0Hz

max@luxBox:~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_60.00
```

After this command my screen adjusted and now looks like it's 2560x1440. One would think I'd be set, but no! For whatever reason it's all just scaled to look like it's 1440p, it's still just as blurry as it was at 1080p. And the blurriness is not my monitor, my windows 8.1 OS looks nice and crisp! If anyone has any suggestions they'd be more than  little welcome!